# How to make sense of Keras documentation, e.g. where is the information on the accuracy metrics?

Tags: keras

I am trying to learn how to use neural networks via Keras in Python. I have been  following tutorials, but I sometimes try to explore beyond the scope of the tutorial, which leads me to do some reading of the Keras documentation.

A few times now, I have not been able to find the information that I am looking for. For example, the is no information on the 'accuracy' metric. In fact, if I were to rely solely on the documentation, I would think that the 'accuracy' metric doesn't actually exist.

My question is, am I reading the documentation wrong? Is the accuracy metric actually a part of a different package?

I sort of anticipate that I will get roasted for this question. Apologies if it is dumb. I trying to learn how to learn better.

I have been looking in the official documentation [here](https://keras.io/metrics/). The 'accuracy' metric is not mentioned.

I have found [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655972/the-accuracy-metric-purpose) that any deep learning framework has poor documentation, so perhaps this is the simple answer. I'm just looking for some confirmation that I'm not missing something.

edit: Another example is available [loss functions](https://keras.io/losses/). Some example code I tried used 'mse' as the loss function, which gives different results to 'mean_squared_error' loss function. There is no information of 'mse' as a loss function.

e.g.
`model.compile(loss='mse')` gives different results to `model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error')`